# Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?

Tags: bug, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on tags broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken)

I clicked the [podcast](/questions/tagged/podcast) tag when I was at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/bring-back-the-podcast) and I arrived at this page:

[image: screenshot]

What "Featured tab"? How/why did this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically [the same issue as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken), here you noticing moreso that the tab is missing rather than the lack of tagged questions. Which, in itself, is the reason why the tab is missing.

The featured tab is only shown if there exist featured questions to look at under that tag. If there are none, it's removed from the UI to prevent people from haplessly wandering into it.

However, the Stack Exchange Sites track whichever tab you were last browsing as you navigate the site. That way, as you change tags, it'll preserve the tab. This has a consequence of preserving the featured tab even when the next tag has no bounty questions, and is the only method outside of URL manipulation to access this non-existent tab.

Comment: I knew about the tab preservation, but I didn't think preserving featured in this case would be by design. Oh well.

Comment: I figured you did know, but I decided to reformat my answer in case anyone else comes in who isn't aware of it.

Comment: does it mean it's by-design then? Still I believe something could be done about it (i.e. it can be fixed). One idea would be to switch some other tab (pick any) if the last preserved tab doesn't apply to current view. Wouldn't it be better?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki It's most likely by design. I would posit that you make your idea as a proper feature-request, than to leave it here as a comment.