# 'You are on the Featured tab' - but there's no Featured tab

Tags: bug, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab)

The text of the page informs I am on the Featured tab, but the tab panel doesn't seem to confirm that.

[image: Screenshot]

When I saw this for the first time I was a bit lost. If you are interested, this happened after visiting some other tag's featured tab (then the server saves the information 'featured' was my last tab) and switching to some unpopular tag (with no bounties).

Comment: Expected behavior, as mentioned at [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab). It's a collision of the fact that tabs are sticky, and that we hide the tab when there's no bounties on a question.