# "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?"

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, bountied-tab

The question [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab) reported this behavior as a bug; a moderator suggested posting it as a feature request, but the questioner never did that. I'm doing so now. (I didn't see a post where someone else did so.)

To summarize:

- I clicked on the "c" tag, then selected the "featured" tab.
- Then I went back to the front page and clicked on the "bash" tag. Since that tag currently has no featured questions, I got:

> You are on the Featured tab.
>
> There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
>
> Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

Well, yes, I certainly would, but I can't easily do so. From that state, the only way *(edit: or so I thought)* to get back to the "bash" tag is to:

1. Go back to the front page
2. Go to a tag that *does* have a "featured" tab (like "c")
3. Select the "newest" tab
4. Go back to the front page
5. Go back to the "bash" tag

I understand that tabs are sticky, and that not showing tabs for a tag that doesn't have multiple tabs is a deliberate feature, and both features make sense. Perhaps the tabs *should* be shown if you manage to end up on a tab that doesn't exist.

When the "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" message is shown, it should provide a simple way to select a different tab.

**EDIT**: Ok, the feature I originally requested already exists.  I think there's still a problem, though; the message suggests selecting a different tab, and the tabs are there, but *they don't look like tabs*.

I'm sure I'm not the only person who's been confused by this.

So my suggestion is this: **If the currently selected tab doesn't exist, do something to make the other tabs look more like tabs.**  My thought is to add a light dotted rectangle around each fo the tab names, but maybe there's a better way.  (I see someone removed the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag on this question; I'm not sure whether it should be re-added.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The other tabs are still shown even though the `featured` tab isn't (since it isn't applicable):

[image: tag tabs]

All you need to do is click on `newest` directly on this page instead of a jog back to the home page and another tag.

Comment: Argh, you're right.  I didn't notice that because there's no tab-like graphic associated with them unless one of them is actually active.  I hope this question is useful to others who are an unobservant as I am.

Comment: So, maybe we could show the featured tab, if we are already on it, so it would be more obvious that there are tabs?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Yes, that would work.  Currently, if there are no featured questions, the featured tab is nonexistent; instead, treat it as an existing tab that happens to be empty.  (If desired, it could still be omitted if you're not currently on it.)

Comment: this, to me, is the most obnoxious and brain-dead part of the stackexchange system right now. see how you had to put a bright red ring around some light grey text to show us where to click?  why not *do that with the actual design!*  see how the "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" prompt is color-coded to match the Questions tab?  any user not intimately familiar with the system is going to believe they need to select a different one of those buttons, except they're pretty sure (and they're right) that they want the QUESTIONS tab, and they shouldn't care about clicking "newest".

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled upon this myself, take a look at the screenshot here:

[image: tag featured tab problem]

Notice that it also has the 'info' there.  Until I found this question I just didn't think of those as being tabs, but of being the standard buttons you see in a tag interface, and since I never clicked on anything but 'info', I just glossed over the other words.  Seems like it would be a small thing to make those words look like words on a tab (which they individually do if you press one).

Comment: I like Paŭlo Ebermann's suggestion in another comment that the currently selected tab should _always_ be shown in the tab bar, even if it has no content. That would actually keep the tab bar _looking_ like a tab bar, and not just a random list of links.