# How can I be "on the Featured tab" when there is no Featured tab?

Tags: bug, user-interface, new-users, bountied-tab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clicking on tags broken?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken)
>   [“Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/perhaps-youd-like-to-select-a-different-tab)

I understand the Featured tab is purposefully being hidden when there are 0 matches to a selected Tag, but in the case of "You are on the Featured tab", this no longer makes sense and is especially confusing to new users.  Choose and implement one of the following:

1. Show a selected (`class="youarehere"`) Featured tab when on a page that results in "You are on the Featured tab", hide it when user navigates away
2. Link the "select a different tab" prompt to a suitable default, such as "newest"
3. Instead of this page, redirect the user to *something immediately useful* (like an alternate view of "unanswered" with the addition of "There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment, but here are some unanswered ones" - preserve the Featured sticky for later, if you think we care)

Why the current behavior is confusing:

- There is no other instance of the word "Featured" on the page *("Featured tab? where?")*
- Styling of "Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" (`class="hot"`) causes it to be visually associated with the Main Nav bar *(and if user re-clicks Questions "tab", their Tag selection is abandoned)*
- Capitalization of "Featured" reinforces false relationship to Main Nav *(actual tabs are all lowercase)*

If the only thing holding options 2 or 3 back is the lack of a consensus default/redirect location, why not re-purpose the same mechanism that delivered me here (the cookie that remembered I "wanted" the Featured tab) to track which tab I click next, and send me *there* next time I arrive at this message?  Short of that, Option 1 should be fairly simple to implement.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['You are on the Featured tab' - but there's no Featured tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90716/you-are-on-the-featured-tab-but-theres-no-featured-tab), [Clicking on tags broken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken), [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab), [“Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/perhaps-youd-like-to-select-a-different-tab)

Comment: @CodyGray would it have helped to mark this as [meta-tag:feature-request] and reword the title something like "Improve site appearance/behavior when selecting a tag with no active bounties"? three of those questions were "what's going on, I don't understand?", with the answers coming in the realm of "by design". [the fourth](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107347/perhaps-youd-like-to-select-a-different-tab) (before editing) was a request for "a way to select a different tab" and so the correct selected answer was "they're there, see?". where would my ideas be better presented?

Comment: Indeed, it appeared to me that you were filing a bug report, asking how you can be on the featured tab when there *is* no featured tab. That's a reasonable question, and 3 other people had the same question before. But each of them received good answers to that question, so I voted to close this as a duplicate—no hard feelings. And yes, the existing UI is apparently by design, that's the other message that the duplicate links attempted to convey.

Comment: You *might* be able to post a new question tagged [meta-tag:feature-request] with some *specific* ideas on how to improve the UI, but there's no guarantee that won't be closed as a duplicate, too, considering that the existing UI is apparently by design. There *is* a message shown that attempts to explain the problem; that's what [Rebecca's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107349/153008) shows. So I'm not sure what else we'd improve.

Comment: I thought the numbered items in the question were fairly specific?

Comment: how about http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125942/181267 ?