# Can't search for keyword [selenium] on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search, tag-search

I think the search field is broken in Stack Overflow.  I can't find questions for the keyword [selenium].  I tried both the "Questions" and "Unanswered" tabs.

Comment: Do you mean `keyword` as in `keyword in text` or as in `tag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I think the search field is broken in Stack Overflow.

Well, [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium). Behold:

[image]

Ensure that you have not added [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) to one of your ignored tags and asked the site to hide ignored tags. If you have, the search will appear to succeed and report the correct number of questions found, but you won't actually see any questions listed on the page! You can find these settings under the [preferences tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640205/mr-wanta?tab=prefs) in your user profile.

And if you're still having trouble, make sure that you've read the [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page. It explains how searches work on Stack Overflow, including some advanced tips and tricks that you can use.

---

> Ah, I reproduced it! Click on "Questions" tab, then click on "featured" tab. Then search for [selenium]. That tab disappears, and then you're left with no sub-tab selected, thus no results.

Right. Because there are no featured questions for the [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) tag. **But it tells you that**, in literally giant text on the page, and even suggests that you switch tabs to find the other questions. How in the world can you call that "unintuitive"?

[image: You are on the Featured tab. There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?]

> What is the best way to submit a bug report for this? It seems like if there aren't any results, it should tell you "Please highlight a tab" or "0 results for featured" (instead of making the tab disappear) or default to "newest"

**It does!** (See above for details.)

Comment: That's goofy.  I have to click on a sub-tab after clicking on the Questions tab?  I'm trying to figure out how this is intuitive.  Should I put in a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: @Mr.Wanta: I didn't click any subtabs. I typed `selenium` into the search box and pressed `Enter`. It absolutely doesn't matter what page you do this from, as long as the search field is visible. I can't understand why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah, I reproduced it!  Click on "Questions" tab, then click on "featured" tab.  Then search for [selenium].  That tab disappears, and then you're left with no sub-tab selected, thus no results.  What is the best way to submit a bug report for this?  It seems like if there aren't any results, it should tell you "Please highlight a tab" or "0 results for featured" (instead of making the tab disappear) or default to "newest".

Comment: @Mr.Wanta: I've updated my answer. I still don't see the need for a bug report.

Comment: That's fine.  But I see this as unintuitive, don't you?  How should I have to remember what tab I selected before I did the search, and then it's all of a sudden gone?  Software shouldn't do tricks on you like that.  It should still keep that tab open--then it wouldn't need that entire explanation.  Does that make sense?  I'll give you a point regardless for helping me.

Comment: I've seen this problem brought up multiple times on multiple SE sites now. It is a truly horrible user experience. I really think this is something that needs to get changed. Perhaps a `feature-request` is in order...

Comment: @Mr.Wanta: It doesn't seem like a trick to me. That tab is still selected, that's why it's showing you that message. The only thing tricky is that tabs are not shown when they don't contain any questions. This has been discussed here on Meta before; see [Why did clicking on a tag take me to a nonexistent tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88036/why-did-clicking-on-a-tag-take-me-to-a-nonexistent-tab), and [Clicking on tags broken?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78989/clicking-on-tags-broken)

Comment: @Charles: I've linked two places where this has been previously discussed here. If you'd like, you can turn one of them into a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails and the StackOverflow hamsters are asleep at the wheel, [ask Mr. Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=selenium%20site:stackoverflow.com). Check out the first returned result:

[image]